# Discord.js TypeError: message.guild.createRole is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error when coding a discord.js bot.

```
TypeError: message.guild.createRole is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.run (/app/commands/myakish.js:7:36)
    at Client.bot.on (/app/bot.js:70:7)
    at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9ebd7b80-3cef-449a-8d8e-f2bc76449720/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/9ebd7b80-3cef-449a-8d8e-f2bc76449720/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
```

Comment: Hi! and welcome to the Overflow. To get an answer to your question it's a good idea to give us as much information as possible. for example, a good description of what you are trying to accomplish, a code snippet and what you've tried to solve this issue. I see you already using the Markdown! great stuff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you are using Discord.js v12.

---

In Discord.js v12,

```js
Guild.createRole()
```

changed to:

```js
Guild.roles.create()
```

---

I've created a simple example for you:

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {name: "My Role"}
}).then(role => {
    message.channel.send(`${role.name} created!`);
});
```

Comment: I am but do you know a way to switch back to v11?                                          PS: I get guild and role not defined

Comment: You can use `npm install discord.js@version`. For example: `npm install discord.js@11.6.4`.
As for the error, I need to see your entire code to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

in V12 this command is `"role" = message.guild.roles.create`
you can use this in our code in v12 just put your role in there like :
Owner = message.guild.roles.create(
name: "Owner"
);